# Render Attributes remain hidden if VF page rerendered

Tags: visualforce, rerender, rendered

I have a VF page for opportunity products with many fields rendered conditionally based on the user, product and/or the opportunity.  The page works great except we have a button that subtracts the Pd product amount from the main product amount for users and then rerenders the form/page.  The subtraction works and saves properly and the page rerenders however, when it rerenders all fields/sections on the page that are rendered conditionally disappear. Most of the changes made in the fields are still saved before it rerenders but it does clear anything that is in the Subject multiselect picklist even if it is previously saved information.  Any idea why it the render attributes aren't working when it rerenders and what I can do to fix it?  Thanks

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OLIController">
    <apex:pagemessages />
    <style>
        td:empty {
        visibility: hidden;
        }

        tr.bordered {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Products">
            <table class="empty">
                <apex:repeat var="OLI" value="{!OLIs}" id="newProduct">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">Product Name</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">Subtotal</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">Discount
                                Amount</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">Credit
                                Amount</div>
                        </td>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!OR(CONTAINS(profilename, 'Sales Operations'), CONTAINS(profilename, 'SalesOps'))}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Closed Amount" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Closed NB Amount" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(CONTAINS(opportunity.Type,'Pilot'), !CONTAINS(opportunity.Type,'Conversion'), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'),!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'))}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Potential Pilot Conversion Amount" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(CONTAINS(recordTypeName, 'Renewal'), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'))}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Renewal Basis" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Expansion Amount" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Downgrade Reason" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:black;font-size: 15px">
                                <apex:outputText value="{!OLI.Product2.Name}" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputfield id="UnitPrice" value="{!OLI.UnitPrice}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputfield id="Discount_Amount__c"
                                value="{!OLI.Discount_Amount__c}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputfield id="Credit_Amount__c" value="{!OLI.Credit_Amount__c}" />
                        </td>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!OR(CONTAINS(profilename, 'Sales Operations'), CONTAINS(profilename, 'SalesOps'))}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Closed_Amount__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Closed_Amount__c}" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Closed_NB_Amount__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Closed_NB_Amount__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(CONTAINS(opportunity.Type,'Pilot'), NOT(CONTAINS(opportunity.Type,'Conversion')), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'),!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'))}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Potential_Pilot_Conversion_Amount__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Potential_Pilot_Conversion_Amount__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(CONTAINS(recordTypeName, 'Renewal'), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'))}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Renewal_Basis__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Renewal_Basis__c}" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Expansion_Amount__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Expansion_Amount__c}" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Downgrade_Reason__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Downgrade_Reason__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <apex:outputText>
                                <div
                                    style="color:white;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;align-content: center;margin-top: 20px">
                                    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                </div>
                            </apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">Product
                                Specific Notes</div>
                        </td>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'))}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="# of Students" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(NOT(CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD')),CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Education'))}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="# of Teachers" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'),!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'))}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Contract Term" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'), CONTAINS(recordTypeName, 'Renewal'))}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Expiring Term" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD')}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Preferred PD Date" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'IXL Learning')}">
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Grade Levels" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div style="color:black;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                                    <apex:outputText value="Subject" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputfield id="Product_Specific_Notes__c"
                                value="{!OLI.Product_Specific_Notes__c}" />
                        </td>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'))}">
                            <td class="empty">
                                <apex:inputfield id="of_Students__c" value="{!OLI.of_Students__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(NOT(CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD')),CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Education'))}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="of_Teachers__c" value="{!OLI.of_Teachers__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'),!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'))}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Contract_Term__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Contract_Term__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel
                            rendered="{!AND(!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD'), !CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'Workbook'), CONTAINS(recordTypeName, 'Renewal'))}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Expiring_Term__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Expiring_Term__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'PD')}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Preferred_PD_Date__c"
                                    value="{!OLI.Preferred_PD_Date__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CONTAINS(OLI.Product2.Name, 'IXL Learning')}">
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Grade_Levels__c" value="{!OLI.Grade_Levels__c}" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <apex:inputfield id="Subject__c" value="{!OLI.Subject__c}" />
                            </td>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                        <td colspan="8">
                            <apex:outputText>
                                <div
                                    style="color:black;font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;align-content: center;margin-top: 40px;margin-bottom: 10px;border-bottom: 2px solid #000">

                                </div>
                            </apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="100%" style="border-bottom:1px solid black"></td>
                    </tr>

                </apex:repeat>
            </table>

            <div align="center">
                <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!cancel}"
                        styleClass="btn"
                        style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                    </apex:commandButton>

                    <apex:commandLink value="Save & Return" action="{!saveandreturn}"
                        target="_parent" styleClass="btn"
                        style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">
                    </apex:commandlink>
                    <apex:commandButton rerender="" value="Subtract PD Amount from Main Product"
                        action="{!recalcsave}" oncomplete="recalculate();" />

                    <apex:actionFunction action="{!recalculatetotal}" name="recalculateAF"
                        rerender="form" />

                    <script>
                        function recalculate() {
                        recalculateAF();
                        return null;
                        }

                    </script>


                </apex:pageblockButtons>
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class OLIController {
  public ApexPages.StandardController sc;
  public Opportunity Opp { get; set; }
  public List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIs { get; set; }
  public String recordTypeName { get; set; }
  public String profilename { get; set; }
  public Integer total { get; set; }
  public Decimal PDAmount { get; set; }
  public Decimal ProductAmount { get; set; }
  public Decimal NewProductAmount { get; set; }

  public OLIController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    this.Opp = (Opportunity) sc.getRecord();
    OLIs = [
      SELECT
        Name,
        Contract_Term__c,
        Expiring_Term__c,
        Renewal_Basis__c,
        Opportunity.Renewal_Basis__c,
        Downgrade_Reason__c,
        Quantity,
        Subtotal,
        ID,
        Product2ID,
        Product2.Name,
        Discount,
        Discount_Amount__c,
        Credit_Amount__c,
        Product_Specific_Contact__c,
        Product_Specific_Notes__c,
        Preferred_PD_Date__c,
        Expansion_Amount__c,
        Grade_Levels__c,
        UnitPrice,
        of_Teachers__c,
        of_Students__c,
        PLS_Type__c,
        Subject__c,
        Potential_Pilot_Conversion_Amount__c,
        Closed_Amount__c,
        Closed_NB_Amount__c,
        OpportunityId
      FROM OpportunityLineItem
      WHERE OpportunityId = :Opp.Id
    ];
    recordTypeName = [
      SELECT Name
      FROM RecordType
      WHERE Id = :this.Opp.recordTypeId
    ][0]
    .name;
    Id profileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
    profileName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :profileId].Name;
  }

  public List<OpportunityLineItem> getOLIs() {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIs = [
      SELECT
        Name,
        Subtotal,
        Renewal_Basis__c,
        Opportunity.Renewal_Basis__c,
        Downgrade_Reason__c,
        Contract_Term__c,
        Discount,
        Expiring_Term__c,
        Quantity,
        Product2ID,
        ID,
        Discount_Amount__c,
        Credit_Amount__c,
        Product_Specific_Contact__c,
        Product_Specific_Notes__c,
        Preferred_PD_Date__c,
        Expansion_Amount__c,
        Grade_Levels__c,
        UnitPrice,
        of_Teachers__c,
        of_Students__c,
        PLS_Type__c,
        Subject__c,
        Potential_Pilot_Conversion_Amount__c,
        Closed_Amount__c,
        Closed_NB_Amount__c,
        OpportunityId
      FROM OpportunityLineItem
      WHERE OpportunityId = :Opp.Id
    ];

    return OLIs;
  }

  // controller method to get gross total of products
  public Decimal getGrossTotal() {
    Decimal grossTotal = 0;
    for (OpportunityLineItem pw : OLIs) {
    }
    return grossTotal;
  }

  // controller method to recalculate product total
  public void recalculate() {
    for (OpportunityLineItem pw : OLIs) {
      if (pw.Name.Contains('PD')) {
        pdAmount = pw.unitPrice * pw.quantity;
      } else {
        productAmount = pw.unitPrice * pw.quantity;
      }
    }
    if (pdAmount != 0 && productAmount != 0) {
      NewProductAmount = ProductAmount;
    }
  }

  // controller method to calculate product total minus PD Amount
  public void recalculatetotal() {
    for (OpportunityLineItem pw : OLIs) {
      if (pw.Name.Contains('PD')) {
        pdAmount = pw.unitPrice * pw.quantity;
      } else {
        productAmount = pw.unitPrice * pw.quantity;
      }
    }
    if (pdAmount != 0 && productAmount != 0) {
      NewProductAmount = ProductAmount - PDAmount;
    }
    for (OpportunityLineItem pw2 : OLIs) {
      if (NewProductAmount != 0 && !pw2.Name.Contains('PD')) {
        pw2.UnitPrice = NewProductAmount;
      }
    }
  }

  //Trying to calculate new total
  public PageReference recalcsave() {
    update OLIs;
    return null;
  }

  public PageReference QuickSave() {
    update OLIs;
    return ApexPages.currentPage();
    /*
        PageReference tempPage = ApexPages.currentPage();            
        tempPage.setRedirect(true);
        return tempPage; */
  }

  public PageReference saveandreturn() {
    try {
      update OLIs;
      PageReference result = new PageReference('/' + this.Opp.Id);
      result.setRedirect(true);
      return result;
    } catch (DMLException de) {
      Apexpages.addMessage(
        new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, de.getDmlMessage(0))
      );
      return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Apexpages.addMessage(
        new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, e.getMessage())
      );
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @sfdcfox!  I wasn't sure if you were just making my code more legible or if some of the edits would fix the issue so I went ahead and put them in.  I also added a line in the recalculate total method to update the OLIs again since it didn't seem to be saving the change to the actual sales price.  But after the save it's still only showing the fields that don't have any rendering attributes.  Any idea why it's doing that?  And with the other fields not showing that's when the subject field gets cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution!  Adding layout=none to each of the output panels fixed the rerendering issue.  If anyone knows WHY that fixed it I would be interested.